# Is Driver registering by `Class.forName()` needed in mysql-connector 8.0?

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, mysql-8.0

I already know from on **JDBC 4.0.** and **JDK 6**, drivers those are found in classpath are automatically loaded. This is the reason we are used to ignoring that `Class.forName(dbDriver);` line of code when creating JDBC connection.

But recently I installed **MySQL Server 8.0.11** and I updated the driver to  `mysql-connector-java:8.0.11` in my simple Servlet project that runs on **tomcat 8.5.30**. But it gives me the infamous exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql at ...
```

But all my code was working and fine before. So then I added the `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

And it works. I think I didn't miss anything. Can anyone explain to me what it might be the reason?

Comment: There is no JDBC 8.0, the latest JDBC specification version is 4.3. You are confusing the driver version with the JDBC specification version.

Comment: thanks for correcting @MarkRotteveel

Answer (score 5):

The JDBC 4.0 (and higher) automatic driver loading works only if the driver jar is on the initial (system) class path of the application. If you are using Tomcat, the driver would have to be in the `<catalina-home>/lib` folder.

If you deploy the driver together with your application, then the driver is on the context classpath of that specific application, and it will need to be explicitly loaded using `Class.forName`.

But in practice, you should not be using `DriverManager.getConnection` to create connections in a web application. You should be using a data source (preferably with connection pooling), either created and initialized in code, or in the context or server configuration of Tomcat. In that case this problem wouldn't even surface, because either the data source already knows how to get the driver, or you have to explicitly configure it with the driver to use anyway.

Comment: thanks for explaining Mark. I know these good practices. And the application contains the driver in its context path as it was for `mysql-jdbc-connector 5`. My point is what makes it different having driver version to 8 ? Could you lit some light on that ?

Comment: @ShafinMahmud There is no difference, with MySQL Connector/J 5.1.x you'd get the same behavior.